# How can I prevent users from circumventing the Windows hosts file?

Tags: windows, blocking, hosts

I realized Windows hosts entries can easiliy be circumvented by just setting a system proxy or use a webproxy like [hide my ass](http://hidemyass.com/).

How can prevent my kids from circumventing my hosts file that blocks all the porn sites?

Comment: It was game over once you gave your kids admin rights. Put that right as a first step.

Comment: OpenDNS Parental Controls: http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A host file is meant to make domain names available not block them. The ability to block sites useing a hostfile is more of a side effect that can easily be circumvented, even without any further tools (just use the IP instead of the domain name).

If you need reliable blocking, a host file is not the correct tool. Use some kind of firewall or webfilter for this.